# I want to disable the delete options to some of my dynamic cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have created a custom cell called `totalCell` and I want to disable the delete by sliding. I want it to work with just the other type of cells. How can I do it ?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            cells[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

            let totalCellIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 3)
            let totalCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: totalCellIndexPath) as! totalTableViewCell
            let total = self.updateTotalLabel()
            totalCell.totalLabel!.text = String(total)
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [totalCellIndexPath], with: .fade)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `canEditRowAt`. It's more efficient than distinguish the cases in `editingStyleForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return indexPath != [3, 0]
}
```